# primefaces checkbox datatable will not check boxes on ajax event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to get a primefaces checkbox datatable to select multiple rows and pass those values to the bean. I have an ajax event for rowSelect and that works fine, but the ajax for rowSelectCheckbox never fires and it is as if my checkboxes are 'unclickable'. When selecting a row the rowSelect ajax event fires and highlights the entire row and checks the checkbox. However, I am unable to check any other checkboxes off so it is obvious only the rowSelect ajax works and not the rowSelectCheckbox. Here is code:

```
<p:dataTable   id="content-table"
                   var="obj"
                   value="#{releaseNotes.contentList}"
                   rows="5"
                   paginator="true"
                   style="width:100%"
                   selectionMode="multiple"
                   selection="#{releaseNotes.selectedContent}"
                   rowKey="#{obj.hashCode()}"
                   paginatorPosition="bottom"
                   rendered="#{releaseNotes.showContentTable}">
                   <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{releaseNotes.selectListenerCode}" update=":grids :buttons" immediate="true"/>
                   <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{releaseNotes.checkBoxListener}" update=":grids :buttons" immediate="true" />  
                   <f:facet name="header">Content</f:facet>

                   <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
                   <c:forEach items="#{releaseNotes.columnNames}" var="columnName">

                        <p:column headerText="#{columnName.toLowerCase().replace('_', ' ')}"
                         filterBy="#{obj.get(columnName)}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{obj.get(columnName)}"/>
                        </p:column>
                   </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance, my first post so I apologize if I missed some etiquette for the code formatting or anything like that, just let me know I will not take offense....